# ASP.NET MVC5 Identity with only Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am writing a web-application with plenty large amount of data. Consequently, I use Enterprise Library - Data Access block and repository pattern. Till this moment I didn't use Entity Framework. Now I need to implement authentication and roles with ASP.NET Identity. Is there any approaches to implement these only with EL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to implement your custom Membership and Role providers and use them in your application.